AmbiguousForeignKeysError in SQLAlchemy: Resolving Foreign Key Relationship in Flask Models
I'm facing an issue with SQLAlchemy in my Flask application. I have two models: User and AssignmentReminder. Both models have foreign key relationships with the users.id column in the User model, but I'm getting the following error when I try to run my app:
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.assignments

Models:
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    assignments = db.relationship('AssignmentReminder', backref='user', lazy=True)

class AssignmentReminder(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'assignments'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    due_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)

    creator = db.relationship('User', back_populates='assignments')
    recipient = db.relationship('User', back_populates='assignments_received')

Issue:
I’m getting an AmbiguousForeignKeysError because SQLAlchemy cannot determine which foreign key to use for the relationship between User and AssignmentReminder. Both user_id and recipient_id refer to users.id, but SQLAlchemy doesn't know which one to use for the assignments relationship.
What I’ve Tried:

I have defined both user_id and recipient_id as foreign keys that reference the users.id column in the User model.
I attempted to define relationships in the User model to refer to both assignments and assignments_received, but I’m still encountering the AmbiguousForeignKeysError.
I tried using foreign_keys in the db.relationship() to explicitly specify which foreign key should be used, but it didn’t resolve the issue.

What I Expected:

I expected SQLAlchemy to correctly infer the relationship between the User and AssignmentReminder models, given that both user_id and recipient_id are foreign keys referencing users.id.
I also expected that using foreign_keys in the relationship definition would help SQLAlchemy distinguish between the two foreign keys, resolving the ambiguity.

Question:
How can I fix the AmbiguousForeignKeysError and make sure that SQLAlchemy can correctly resolve the foreign key relationship between User and AssignmentReminder?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To define the foreign keys needed for the specific join, you can specify the required keys in a list within the relationship using the keyword foreign_keys. See "Handling Multiple Join Paths" in the documentation for an explanation.

Since the relationship is bidirectional, both models must specify the foreign keys associated with the particular relationships:
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    assignments = db.relationship(
        'AssignmentReminder',
        back_populates='creator',
        foreign_keys='AssignmentReminder.user_id',
        ...
    )
    assignments_received = db.relationship(
        'AssignmentsReminder',
        back_populates='recipient',
        foreign_keys='AssignmentReader.recipient_id',
        ...
    )

class AssignmentReminder(db.Model):
    ...
    creator = db.relationship(
        'users',
        back_populates='assignemnts',
        foreign_keys=user_id,
        ...
    )
    recipient = db.relationship(
        'users',
        back_populates='assignemnts_received',
        foreign_keys=recipient_id,
        ...
    )

In SQLAlchemy 2.0-style syntax, the equivalent definitions would be:
class User(Base):
    ...
    assignemnts: Mapped[list['AssignemntsReminder']] = orm.relationship(
        back_populates='creator',
        foreign_keys='AssignmentReminder.user_id',
        ...
    )
    assignments_received: Mapped[list['AssignemntsReminder']] = orm.relationship(
        back_populates='recipient',
        foreign_keys='AssignmentReminder.recipient_id',
        ...
    )

class AssignmentReminder(Base):
    ...
    creator: Mapped[Assignment] = orm.relationship(
        back_populates='assignments',
        foreign_keys=user_id,
        ...
    )
    recipient: Mapped[Assignment] = orm.relationship(
        back_populates='assignments_received',
        foreign_keys=recipient_id,
        ...
    )


hi @snakecharmerb this problem has been solved thank you

@yabegitulah the purpose of answering is not just to help you, but to help others who might have the same problem in future.

Okay @snakecharmerb
